# Library not found for -lBraintree

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have added Braintree with other lib using pods. My build is failed because it can't find library for Braintree. Here's what I have:

> ld: library not found for -lBraintree
>
> clang error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Things I've tried:

1. Used `.xcworkspace` instead of `.xcodeproj`
2. Set build active architecture NO
3. Removed any red `lib.a`

This is what my project looks like:

[image]

[image]
[image]

I don't see a `-lBraintree` flag in the last picture yet it shows here `-ObjC -ObjC -l"AdIdAccessLibrary" -l"Braintree" -l"DI...` why?

**Podfile**

```
target 'MyProject' do

pod 'Braintree', '3.9.3'
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'GoogleIDFASupport'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'

end

target 'MyProjectTests' do
end
```

Comment: Can you post your podfile?

Comment: check the added podfile

Comment: Is there any reason you install the spesific version 3.9.3?

Comment: Yes that's project specific